# How does {% load url from future %} and namespaces work in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, dynamic, future

Can someone show me an example (plus a small explanation) of how **{% load url from future %}** and **namespace** concept works?

I'm new in python and django and i need to learn how not to make hardcoded urls and also how to use other functions like reverse().

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    """
      This one is what i did first but works with hardcoded url inside 
      top-navigator.html:
      url(r'^books/$', 'books.views.book_index'),

      The next one is what i'm trying to do:
      (but of course is not correct)
    """
    url(r'^books/$', include('books.views.book_index', namespace='books')),
)
```

---

**top-navigator.html**

when i'm trying to run the server is shows the error:

> Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named book_index

```
{% load url from future %}

<div class="navbar-inner">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'books:book_index' %}">Books</a></li>
    <li><a href="/authors">Authors</a></li>
    <li><a href="/publishers">Publishers</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What can i do in order do to something similar for all the links?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi

Answer (score 0):

To use namespaces and the `include` statement, you *must* import another urls.py file with `patterns` in it.

You can't just `include` a view as you've done here.

Change your code to

```
{% url 'book_index' %}"

url(r'^books/$', 'books.views.book_index', name='books'))
```

Or to use namespaces for illustration purposes:

```
more_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'book.views.book_index', name='book_index')),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^books/', include(more_patterns, namespace='books')),
                            #^^^^^^^ note you would normally use a string that points
                            #        to a python file containing urls.
)

{% url 'books:book_index' %} will now resolve.
```